# How to store cookie in socket.io (socket.handshake.headers.cookie)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I set cookie with help of setcookie($name, $value) in php.

Then:

```
socket.on('connection', function(socket) {

    var parse = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
    console.log(parse);
}
```

And I receive only something like this

```
{ 'connect.sess': 's:j:{}.CoRLkkQvzo1011EOxT2IdmJh5rqejQ0m5dp0XGFCIz4' }
```

socket.handshake.headers.cookie doesn't store all of my cookie ?

Comment: Cookies usually are not shared across different domains, I assume your cookie is bound to one domain (can be IP with Port) and then is not sent to another domain.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. The following links helped me solve my problem.

- [How do sessions work in Express.js with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522020/how-do-sessions-work-in-express-with-nodejs)
- [nodeJS - How to create and read session with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765777/node-js-how-to-create-and-read-session-with-express)
- [Interesting Blog Post](http://notjustburritos.tumblr.com/post/22682186189/socket-io-and-express-3)

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what about socket.handshake.headers.cookie ? As I saw in the second link, email was saved in the session from request params, e.g. req.param('email'). But I try to set cookie before socket.on('connection',....) and then try to get it from socket.handshake.headers.cookie.

Comment: Session data is stored server-side in NodeJS. A session is not stored in a cookie, but instead, the cookie (with its sid) is what tells the server which session is associated with the client.

Comment: I use socket.io to exchange information between two servers, e.g. between main site on one server and node.js on another server. As you see, I have different hosts. As I understand, http requests are not sended to node.js, because I use only socket.io for socket.emit and socket.on. I don't understand how session can help me ? But as far as I know, when client connects to the server on node js, e.g. socket.on('connection') event rises, client sends http reqiest with headers, that store clients cookie in socket.handshake.headers.cookie.

Comment: But as was mentioned before, cookies usually are not shared across different domains (I have two hosts). Therefore I need to try to set domain (node.js host) param in setcookie(). I think, I cant even set this sid, because users are not visit the site directly.

Comment: What do you think about this ?