# How to access cookie data inside a socket.io connection?

Tags: node.js, sockets, cookies, socket.io

I am using node.js and socket.io. on the client side, I wrote a cookie like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
document.cookie="foo=bar";
socket.emit('this', { is: 'test'});
```

and on the server side, I need to be able to read from that cookie inside a socket.io connection, something like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('this', function(reqData){ 
        console.log(socket.handshake.headers); // there is no cookies here!
    });
}
```

a no-framework solution is preferred, any help is appreciated.
thanks.

**update:** in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nasser-torabzade/7054775) you can find my complete code.

Comment: Please see this question: [how-to-store-cookie-in-socket-io-socket-handshake-headers-cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446602/how-to-store-cookie-in-socket-io-socket-handshake-headers-cookie/19451088#19451088)

Comment: @MatthiasHoldorf thanks for your help, but I've already seen that. some third party modules are involved, and some parts of answers are outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cookie before making the connection from the client:

```
document.cookie = "foo=bar";
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.emit('this', { is: 'test'});
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/9ffac71c18e113baf9db) is a minimal example that I tested with. The server console.log's a new cookie with each reload of the page, as expected.

Comment: @Nasser it does for me. Is your HTML being served by the same app?

Comment: I think so! I have two separated functions in my app, one for serving files like this: 
`http.createServer(onRequest).listen(httpPort);
function onRequest (request, response) {
   // stuff for serving files
}`
and another function for serving socket.io:
`io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   // stuff for handling events
}`
and these two are called in my index.js , Do you think I need to change this architecture?

Comment: @Nasser `httpPort` is 3000? Does the code in my gist work for you?

Comment: in my app, `socketPort` and `httpPort` are different. and no your gist didn't work for me. can you please check my code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nasser-torabzade/7054775)? thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @Nasser you took your gist offline again? gives a 404.

Comment: no, github was down for maintenance(my bad luck!). it's ok now.

Comment: @Nasser I changed a code a bit to make it work, but the cookies seem to be sent just fine with your code too.