# Session handling in mean stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, meanjs

I am new to MEAN stack, presently the mean stack is inserting sessions to mongodb:

```
app.use(session({
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  //cookie: { maxAge: 600  },
  secret: config.sessionSecret,
  store: newmongoStore({
    db: db.connection.db,
    collection: config.sessionCollection
  })
}));
```

But I want to save some custom variables in that session & access them across requests, I did not get how to save it in session. Let's say I want to save `mydata` in session, I saw some examples & tried like:

```
req.session.mydata = 'projectdata';
req.session.cookie.mydata = 'projectdata';
```

Both are not working. Also I want to update `maxAge` variable on every request to server side, how to do it? Kindly help me.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are saving into `req.session`?

Comment: It's already there in my question. According to below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765777/node-js-how-to-create-and-read-session-with-express i did like: req.session.mydata = 'projectdata'; and req.session.cookie.mydata = 'projectdata';

Comment: Are you using `express-session`?

Comment: yes. MEAN [Mongo Express Angular Node] stack. app.use(session({
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  //cookie: { maxAge: 600 },
  secret: config.sessionSecret,
  store: new mongoStore({
   db: db.connection.db,
   collection: config.sessionCollection
  })
 }));

Comment: Don't post code in comments, and please, format your code in your question

Answer (score 1):

Better use Token based sessions, It will help you making you API universal ie, You can also use the same API for mobile applications.
Try implementing Token Based Authentication using psJwt.
You will find good articles for this on scotch.io and on Plural sight.