# How to get back again user's credentials when authentication fails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap, passport.js, ldapauth

I'm using npm passport-ldapauth module and I want to recover the user credentials when the authentications fails so that I can apply with the same credentials another login strategy. Is there any way to obtain this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you have to pass the username/password to `passport-ldapauth` in the first place?

Comment: I get it from HTML body but when it fails I don't have that information accessible.

Comment: Why not keep it somewhere you can still access it?

Comment: Because I don't have any way to keep it, so I need that the ldapauth-passport in case that it fails, it also returns my the request. I was searchin an optional parameter to obtain this, but I didnt't find nothing about it.

Comment: There is always a way :) For example, search for "session variables node.js" and you will find results like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765777/nodejs-how-to-create-and-read-session-with-express).