# How can save session of user in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a Node.JS user tracker. I want to save an online users session for tracking that.

Tracker file:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('connect', function (socket) {});
```

Node.js main file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen( 3000 );

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  // I WANT HERE => to know specific user ( after some user refresh )

});
```

Comment: You can use cookies to handle it.

Comment: How ? can you explain more ..?

Comment: When connection in node.js occured, save `socket.id` as cookie for your user.

Answer (score 0):

You need a session manager.

1. Install express
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/express
2. Install express-session
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Comment: Unfortunately i dont use like this: `app.get('/', ....` , so i can handle with `req`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Express` to do so.
After importing Express, you can use `Express.session`.

The following link will help you out further:
[nodeJS - How to create and read session with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765777/nodejs-how-to-create-and-read-session-with-express)

Answer (score 0):

You can use express-session Module to maintain the session , You can simply use a redis store to save the session.

```
var session = require('express-session')
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

// Set up our session store. This will use Redis as our session management.
app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: "*****",
    store: new RedisStore()
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dont have redis in my server and i cant install :(